# Is there any way to use incrementing number as call to methods with different number in every iteration

Tags: java, android

What I'm showing is what I'd like to get but I don't know if it is possible. Basically I want to find 48 `ImageButton` views based on the index `i`.

```java
ImageButton[] buttons;
for (int i = 0; i < 48; i++) {
    buttons[i] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.k_i);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that's not possible. Since you need to pass the view id which is an `int`.
Although you can use the method [findViewWithTag](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewWithTag(java.lang.Object)) which allows you to find views with a specified **tag** (`String`).
You only have to add the attribute `android:tag="button_1"` in the views you want to find. Then you can just do the following.

```java
String baseTag = "button_";
ImageButton[] buttons;
for (int i = 0; i < 48; i++) {
    buttons[i] = (ImageButton) findViewWithTag(baseTag + i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it like this

```
buttons[i] = v.findViewById(Context.getResources().getIdentifier("k_"+i,"id",Context.getPackageName()));
```